# How can I change the default font for .txt files opened in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, configuration, default

It is possible to open .txt files in Libre Office Writer, but unfortunately Liberation Mono is set as default font to display them.

I want to use a different font as a default.

I found `Tools` > `Options` > `LibreOffice Writer` > `Basic Fonts (Western)` but "Liberation Mono" that is the default font for .txt files is not set anywhere.

I am using Libre Office 6.0.2.1 Build ID: 1:6.0.2~rc1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo1